# Securing API Using HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: node.js, api, express, basic-authentication, stripe-payments

I'm looking into HTTP Basic Auth to secure my Nodejs API (using SSL too).

I'm wondering whether both a username and password are required with Basic Auth as I would just like to use a secret API key which would serve as a username. Resources I have read appear to suggest that both are required but Stripe's docs appear to suggest that just a username is sufficient:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication

"*Authentication to the API occurs via HTTP Basic Auth. Provide your API key as the basic auth username. You do not need to provide a password*"

Comment: Just as a reminder, basic auth is *completely insecure* unless you are using HTTPS.

Comment: thanks - I did mention SSL in the first line

Comment: Ah, sorry, my eyes flew right over that.  Nice work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the basicAuth middleware in express to do this http://expressjs.com/api.html#basicAuth. Just set the username(s) to the API key and the password(s) to ' ' (empty string, not double quote).

Comment: Thanks for this - though not sure this middleware is available in Express 4.x. Will probably be able to do the same with Passportjs though

Comment: Passport is great too. See the Custom Callback at the bottom of this page. http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module for HTTP Basic/Digest authentication.

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```